# Analyze SonarQube Eclipse - Caused by: org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I'm using Eclipse Luna (`Build id: 20150109-0600, 64 bits`) on Windows with SonarQube plugin (`SonarQube Java Analyser 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE`)

When I try to Run Analyze, the plugin can connect with the server and download the issues of the last analyze (the problems are shown on SonarQube Issues view), but after that there is this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error status [command: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java.exe -cp D:\temp\sonar-runner-impl1326048247551966004.jar org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain D:\temp\sonar-project7307491695046280128.properties]: 1
at org.sonar.runner.api.ForkedRunner.fork(ForkedRunner.java:199)
at org.sonar.runner.api.ForkedRunner.doExecute(ForkedRunner.java:144)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyseProjectJob.run(AnalyseProjectJob.java:343)
at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyseProjectJob.run(AnalyseProjectJob.java:130)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

The strange thing is that in `D:\temp` there is no file `sonar-runner-implXXX.jar` or `sonar-projectXXX.properties` but there *are* files `sonar-runner-batchXXX.jar` (like `sonar-runner-batch1316679692029245803.jar`)

Another strange thing, the command line is using a JRE 8, but my JAVA_HOME is a JDK 7, the projet where I'm running the Analyze is configured to use a JDK 7 and all my "Installed Jres" on Eclipse are acctually JDKs.

Can someone help me?

========================================================================

Hi

1 - About the temp files, they are really created and then deleted (I made a test "monitoring" the temp file while running the Analyze)

2 - And I could even copy the files and run the command line by hand, in this case i could se the real stack trace:

```
C:\>c:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin\java.exe -cp D:\temp\sonar-runner-impl5987517469765765781.jar org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain D:\temp\sonar-project5904228863019510021.properties
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.3.2
14:01:54.841 INFO  - Preview mode
14:01:54.851 INFO  - Load batch settings
14:01:55.338 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\fred\.sonar\cache
14:01:55.353 INFO  - Install plugins
14:01:55.391 INFO  - Include plugins:
14:01:55.391 INFO  - Exclude plugins: devcockpit, buildstability, pdfreport, report, buildbreaker, scmactivity, views, jira
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: You're not authorized to execute a dry run analysis. Please contact your SonarQube administrator.
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.handleHttpException(ServerClient.java:120)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.download(ServerClient.java:71)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.PreviewDatabase.downloadDatabase(PreviewDatabase.java:85)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.PreviewDatabase.start(PreviewDatabase.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        ... 6 more

C:\>
```

3 - The real problem seems to be a lack of a permission...
But how can I give permission to "dry run analysis" to an user?

========================================================================

3 - I could solve the permission problem adding "Execute Preview Analysis" permission to the users.

4 - Now other error happened: Caused by: org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
And i have no clue about it...

```
C:\>c:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin\java.exe -cp D:\temp\sonar-runner-impl5987517469765765781.jar org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain D:\temp\sonar-project5904228863019510021.properties
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.3.2
14:53:18.370 INFO  - Preview mode
14:53:18.389 INFO  - Load batch settings
14:53:18.794 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\fred\.sonar\cache
14:53:18.814 INFO  - Install plugins
14:53:18.854 INFO  - Include plugins:
14:53:18.854 INFO  - Exclude plugins: devcockpit, buildstability, pdfreport, report, buildbreaker, scmactivity, views, jira
14:53:19.550 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\sgl\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\.sonartmp\preview1422550399090-0
14:53:23.617 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
14:53:26.543 INFO  - Load project settings
14:53:26.634 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
14:53:26.862 INFO  - -------------  Scan sgl
14:53:26.873 INFO  - Load module settings
14:53:27.828 INFO  - Loading technical debt model...
14:53:27.842 INFO  - Loading technical debt model done: 14 ms
14:53:27.842 INFO  - Loading rules...
14:53:28.111 INFO  - Loading rules done: 269 ms
14:53:28.152 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
14:53:28.356 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-01-29)
14:53:28.366 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2014-12-30, analysis of 2015-01-01 02:44:35.053)
14:53:28.376 INFO  - Compare to previous version (2015-01-29)
14:53:28.376 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
14:53:28.485 INFO  - Base dir: D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl
14:53:28.485 INFO  - Working dir: D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\sgl\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core
14:53:28.485 INFO  - Source dirs: D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\webApplication, D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\clientconf, D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\java, D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\conf, D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\conf
14:53:28.485 INFO  - Test dirs: D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\test
14:53:28.485 INFO  - Binary dirs: D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\webApplication\WEB-INF\classes
14:53:28.485 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:53:28.485 INFO  - Index files
14:53:46.434 INFO  - 959 files indexed
14:53:50.916 INFO  - Quality profile for java: Minds Java Profile
14:53:51.088 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
14:53:51.223 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan...
14:53:51.227 INFO  - 946 source files to be analyzed
14:54:01.229 INFO  - 127/946 files analyzed, current is D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\java\br\com\mindsatwork\sgl\model\DatabaseVersion.java
14:54:11.240 INFO  - 176/946 files analyzed, current is D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\java\br\com\mindsatwork\sgl\model\MaterialReservationStatus.java
14:54:21.269 INFO  - 240/946 files analyzed, current is D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\java\br\com\mindsatwork\sgl\model\strategy\AbstractTicketChangeRequestStatusStrategy.java
14:54:31.299 INFO  - 321/946 files analyzed, current is D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\java\br\com\mindsatwork\sgl\permission\ApplicationModuleStrategyCourse.java
14:54:36.119 ERROR - Class not found: org.slf4j.Logger
14:54:41.320 INFO  - 455/946 files analyzed, current is D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\java\br\com\mindsatwork\sgl\web\action\ActionInitSaveCorrectiveMaintenance.java
14:54:51.324 INFO  - 541/946 files analyzed, current is D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\java\br\com\mindsatwork\sgl\web\action\ActionListProvider.java
14:55:01.370 INFO  - 614/946 files analyzed, current is D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\java\br\com\mindsatwork\sgl\web\action\ActionSearch.java
14:55:11.395 INFO  - 674/946 files analyzed, current is D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\java\br\com\mindsatwork\sgl\web\dwr\MessageManager.java
14:55:21.398 INFO  - 748/946 files analyzed, current is D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\java\br\com\mindsatwork\sgl\web\service\model\xstream\WsPackageTrackingMainData.java
14:55:23.288 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:23.650 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:23.781 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:23.890 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:24.429 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:24.531 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:24.657 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:24.757 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:24.877 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:24.982 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:25.102 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:25.212 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:25.332 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:25.437 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:25.537 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:25.639 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:25.731 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:25.931 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:26.022 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:26.127 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:26.295 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:26.398 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:26.479 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:26.560 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:26.665 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:26.786 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:26.878 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:27.438 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:27.741 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:28.152 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:28.366 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:28.457 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:28.556 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:28.631 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:28.709 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:28.801 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:28.873 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:28.953 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:29.026 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:29.355 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:29.435 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:29.624 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:29.694 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:31.380 INFO  - 848/946 files analyzed, current is D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\sgl\src\java\br\com\mindsatwork\sgl\web\taglib\display\export\ReportExcelHssfView.java
14:55:31.436 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:31.536 ERROR - Class not found: javax.el.ELContext
14:55:39.628 INFO  - 946/946 source files analyzed
14:55:39.791 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan done: 108568 ms
14:55:39.880 INFO  - Java bytecode scan...
14:55:41.734 INFO  - Java bytecode scan done: 1854 ms
14:55:41.734 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan...
14:55:41.735 INFO  - 13 source files to be analyzed
14:55:41.964 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan done: 230 ms
14:55:41.964 INFO  - 13/13 source files analyzed
14:55:42.290 INFO  - Package design analysis...
14:55:43.038 INFO  - Package design analysis done: 748 ms
14:55:43.509 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 112421 ms
14:55:43.509 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor...
14:55:43.512 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor done: 3 ms
14:55:43.512 INFO  - Sensor PmdSensor...
14:55:43.515 INFO  - Execute PMD 5.1.1...
14:55:43.546 INFO  - Java version: 1.7
14:55:43.593 INFO  - PMD configuration: D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\sgl\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\pmd.xml
14:55:52.299 INFO  - PMD configuration: D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\sgl\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\pmd-unit-tests.xml
14:55:52.300 INFO  - Execute PMD 5.1.1 done: 8785 ms
14:55:52.328 INFO  - Sensor PmdSensor done: 8816 ms
14:55:52.328 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor...
14:55:52.330 INFO  - parsing D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\sgl\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\build\surefire-reports
14:55:52.330 WARN  - Reports path not found: D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\sgl\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\build\surefire-reports
14:55:52.330 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor done: 2 ms
14:55:52.330 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
14:55:52.373 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 43 ms
14:55:52.374 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
14:55:52.396 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 22 ms
14:55:52.396 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
14:55:52.409 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 13 ms
14:55:52.410 INFO  - Sensor FindbugsSensor...
14:55:52.412 INFO  - Execute Findbugs 2.0.3...
14:55:53.888 INFO  - Findbugs output report: D:\workspaces\workspace-fred\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\sgl\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\findbugs-result.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not execute Findbugs
        at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:154)
        at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsSensor.analyse(FindbugsSensor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:131)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:178)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:199)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:194)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:187)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:56)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:44)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:175)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapContainer.java:163)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
        at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:146)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.SerializableIdiom.visit(SerializableIdiom.java:609)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.BetterVisitor.visitField(BetterVisitor.java:286)
        at org.apache.bcel.classfile.Field.accept(Field.java:92)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.PreorderVisitor.doVisitField(PreorderVisitor.java:266)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.PreorderVisitor.visitJavaClass(PreorderVisitor.java:349)
        at org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass.accept(JavaClass.java:214)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.SerializableIdiom.visitClassContext(SerializableIdiom.java:133)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.DetectorToDetector2Adapter.visitClass(DetectorToDetector2Adapter.java:74)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.analyzeApplication(FindBugs2.java:1209)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:282)
        at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:201)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
        at org.apache.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:147)
        at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:68)
        at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:237)
        at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.bcel.util.SyntheticRepository.loadClass(SyntheticRepository.java:179)
        at org.apache.bcel.util.SyntheticRepository.loadClass(SyntheticRepository.java:127)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.lookupSystemClass(AnalysisContext.java:501)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.DeepSubtypeAnalysis.<clinit>(DeepSubtypeAnalysis.java:39)
        ... 15 more

C:\>
```

========================================================================

Hi

Find a link that report the same error on tomcat and tells that it only happens with JDK 7.

So I change de JDK version used by the Analyze (the project is compiled with JDK 7 64 bits)

I tried:

- JDK 6 32 bits: no error (but a lot of warnings "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError" as project is compiled to java 7)
- JDK 7 32 bits: no error
- JDK 7 64 bits: no error
- JDK 8 64 bits: Caused by: org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15

It seems that Sonar only support JDK 8 on recent versions, since 4.3.

But my Sonar server is 4.3.2, so it should support....

---

OBS: If I compile the project with JDK 8 and then do an Anylize I receive a different error:

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7352
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:110)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:587)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:76)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.XFactory.getXClass(XFactory.java:652)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.setAppClassList(AnalysisContext.java:932)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.setAppClassList(FindBugs2.java:997)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:225)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:201)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking - do you want to know what the error means? Or how to fix it? What is the expected final outcome?

Comment: I want to know how to fix it.

I'm just using the option SonarQube -> Analyze of the plugin.
and Eclipse shows me that error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly the same problem.
The issue was that our sonar server was working with java 7, while the eclipse sonarQube plugin was working with java 8.
(You can check that from Help->About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration tab)
I managed to solve the issue by adding bellow to the eclipse.ini file (located under the eclipse installation library.

> -vm 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin\javaw.exe

(this should come above -vmargs)